# Facebook and Twitter URL to post status

Tags: php, url, social-networking

Is there a method that can post a status to Facebook or Twitter. Twitter has this:

> http://www.twitter.com/?status=This+is+the+status+that+will+be+grabbed+by+Twitter

What about Facebook?

Thanks.

I know about doing it by cURL, but I'm not asking about that :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to publish a status to facebook, [you must use the HTTP POST operation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing).  So, no, there is no GET-based URL via which you can publish an update.

In theory, you could create an HTML form that would POST.  You'd need to get an auth token somehow, though.

Answer (score 3):

How about this link ?
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://yahoo.com

Additionally, With XFBML (+JavaScript SDK) you could use this to generate like and recommend box.

<fb:like href="http://www.yourdomain.com" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" 
action="like" font="arial"></fb:like>

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly right for twitter. Try:

http://twitter.com/?status=Your+Update+Here

Hate to say it, but I don't think it's possible with Facebook. At least, not without an application or some wizardry.

Comment: Not being a Twitter user myself, I'm shocked that this exists. Doesn't this allow anyone to create a malicious link that when you click it posts an arbitrary message to Twitter if you have a login cookie?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't actually post it. All it does is populate the message box.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
facebook.com/ajax/updatestatus.php?av=<user_id>pc=<pcname>
```

should work

Comment: This provides an answer to the question. While this answer may be *false* downvotes are used to signify falseness, not deleting. I have no idea if this is correct or not, I'll let domain expert do their job and vote accordingly.

Comment: this answer is correct and working but it involves very long and complex requests.. thank you @FélixGagnon-Grenier

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you now can via

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.somewebsite.com
```

Check out http://www.sharelinkgenerator.com/ for a url generator for several social sharing sites.

Technically, I guess this prepares a post for you rather than directly posting it...

Answer (score -1):

There is not an option like this for facebook.  To do this, it involves writing an application using their API in order to post any type of status update.

Comment: maybe because it's false?